# Множественная замена строк в текстовом файле

Tags: c#

Есть текстовый файл в котором нужно сделать много различных замен по шаблону. 
Например нужно:

- заменить все табуляции на один пробел: Regex r = new Regex("\t");
- заменить пробелы встречающиеся более двух раз на один: Regex rg = new Regex(" {2,}");
- заменить все переносы строки после запятой на пробел: Regex rg = new Regex(",\r");
- заменить переносы на другую строку встречающиеся более двух раз на два.

  ```
          Regex r = new Regex("\t");
          Regex r2 = new Regex(",\r");
          string str = string.Empty;
          using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(FileName))
          { str = reader.ReadToEnd(); }

          str = r.Replace(str, " ");
          str = r2.Replace(str, ", ");
          using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName))
          { file.Write(str); } // и так далее
  ```

Может есть более компактный и удобный способ.

Comment: В приведенном коде вы зачем то каждый раз перечитываете файл. Прочли 1 раз (раз уж весь в память его поднимаем), поменяли все что нужно, сохранили. Мудрить нужно когда есть требования к памяти.

Comment: Действительно туплю:) Поправил. Может можно лучше?

Comment: Если вас беспокоит скорость, то все ваши операции можно сделать и без регеспов, одним проходом.

Comment: Да скорость то в целом устраивает, просто может код корявый и можно все проще.

Comment: Можно попробовать написать один regexp, который сделает все действия. Можно все шаблоны Regex поместить в список строк и в цикле проходиться, подставлять конкретный шаблон и менять исходную строку.

Comment: Спасибо! В принципе такие варианты рассматривал. Все в один... слишком много шаблонов - потом если что надо будет править, кашу эту не разгрести.